# How can I disable the Ethernet card Power Saving?

Tags: 18.04, power-management, ethernet

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04, and I need to full disable my Ethernet Cart Power Saving.

I don't need to change any other System Power Saving settings, but only the Ethernet Card one.

Also, it would be great to maintain this new setting also after any reboot.

Comment: Maybe try the solution found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044127/usb-ethernet-adapter-realtek-r8153-keeps-disconnecting#:~:text=Blacklisting%20the%20device%20for%20usb%20autosuspend%20solves%20the,USB_BLACKLIST%20and%20add%20an%20entry%20for%20your%20device%3A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some researches I found this:

```
What:       /sys/devices/.../power/control
Date:       January 2009
Contact:    Rafael J. Wysocki <rjw@rjwysocki.net>
Description:
        The /sys/devices/.../power/control attribute allows the user
        space to control the run-time power management of the device.

        All devices have one of the following two values for the
        power/control file:

        + "auto\n" to allow the device to be power managed at run time;
        + "on\n" to prevent the device from being power managed;

        The default for all devices is "auto", which means that they may
        be subject to automatic power management, depending on their
        drivers.  Changing this attribute to "on" prevents the driver
        from power managing the device at run time.  Doing that while
        the device is suspended causes it to be woken up.
```

Source documentation from: [The Kernel Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-power)

So the final solution I found is the following one:

```
sudo echo "on" > /sys/class/net/"$(ls /sys/class/net/ | grep -E '^e')"/power/control
```

The `"$(ls /sys/class/net/ | grep -E '^e')"` block is used to find the first `'e'` device (Ethernet Device Card).

**UPDATE:**
At the end, I managed how to run this script every 5 seconds as `root`, just add the following script as `/etc/cron.d/ethernet-control`

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=""

* * * * * root for i in {1..12}; do (echo 'on' > /sys/class/net/"$(ls /sys/class/net/ | grep -E '^e')"/power/control) 2>/dev/null; sleep 5; done;
```

Comment: I just added 12 loops of 5 seconds everyone to fill the 60 seconds crontab gap

Comment: Is such file modified during runtime even after we've set it to "on" ?

Answer (score 1):

For Kubuntu 22.04.1 (KDE 5.24.7) [kernel 5.15.0-60], I had to "Define a special behavior" to never let the computer sleep.

System Settings > Power Management > Activity Power Settings

> Define a special behavior
>
> > [check] Never shut down computer or let it go to sleep

ADDITIONALLY, NetworkManager would not fully recover the LAN connection *IF* it automatically detected a cable disconnect and reconnect.

SO (eventually), I found that bringing the NIC down and up via the CLI worked consistently.

THUS, in **/etc/network/if-up.d**, I created a file **000-cycle-enp2s0-down-up**
with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
NIC_NAME="enp2s0"

if [[ "$IFACE" != "$NIC_NAME" ]] 
then
  exit 0
fi

/usr/sbin/ip link set $IFACE down
/usr/sbin/ip link set $IFACE up
```

THEN, I made the file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x 000-cycle-enp2s0-down-up
```

AS a result, I now have a reliable SSH and HTTPS connection.

*NOTE: 'enp2s0' is the name of my NIC. You must determine the name of yours. I used the following code and recognized the associated ip address with the NIC name.*

```
ip a|grep "inet "
```

Comment: I had the same problem with my Intel NUC8i5BEK cutting out, particularly when any name resolution was needed. I tried your fix and it worked, even after a few reboots. By the 3rd reboot, the latency came back. I wish I knew how to fix this.