# How do I turn off "Energy Efficient Ethernet" on my ethernet card?

Tags: networking, windows, windows-10, ethernet, 22.04

I recently switched to Ubuntu 22.04. Before that, I used Windows 10. I had to buy a new ethernet card (TP-Link TG-3468) because my mainboard's ethernet port stopped working.
With the ethernet card, ethernet kept disconnecting. After some googling, I disabled "Energy Efficient Ethernet" on Windows. [This screenshot does not depict Windows 10, but it looks the same way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UbtR.png) I now have the same issue on Ubuntu, and I wanted to ask where I can disable the same setting for my ethernet card but on Ubuntu 22.04

Output of `cat /etc/default/grub`:

```
If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

    GRUB_DEFAULT=0
    GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
    GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash igb.EEE=0"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
    
    # Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
    # This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
    # the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
    #GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
    
    # Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
    #GRUB_TERMINAL=console
    
    # The resolution used on graphical terminal
    # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
    # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
    #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
    
    # Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
    #GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
    
    # Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
    #GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
    
    # Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
    #GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Output of `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:a6:e6:54:e3:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.109/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp6s0
       valid_lft 85874sec preferred_lft 85874sec
    inet6 2a02:120b:7f5:cab0:59b5:41c3:736a:687a/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86384sec preferred_lft 14384sec
    inet6 2a02:120b:7f5:cab0:7a76:9c37:2714:87c/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86384sec preferred_lft 14384sec
    inet6 fe80::a39f:468f:9437:b5a7/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`:

```
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8161] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. TP-Link TG-3468 v4.0 Gigabit PCI Express Network Adapter [10ec:8168]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: there's a discussion about this in Linux [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255810/turn-down-the-energy-efficient-ethernet-eee-aka-green-ethernet)

Comment: Please add output of `ip a` to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable the Ethernet card Power Saving?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226192/how-can-i-disable-the-ethernet-card-power-saving)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: Please try temporarily: `sudo ethtool --set-eee enp6s0 eee off` Is there any improvement?

Comment: Yes, it solved my issue. My ethernet card doesn't keep disconnecting all the time, but I just need to find out how to disable it permanently.

Comment: Please check my answer in a few moments.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable Energy Efficient Ethernet in kernel parameters.

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash igb.EEE=0"
```

Save the file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Note:** This setting doesn't work for you because you have a wrong first line of `/etc/default/grub`. You accidentally removed `#` from the beginning.

```
If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
```

should be

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
```

That should disable the feature **after a reboot**.

You can check the status by

```
ethtool --show-eee enp6s0
```

You can also disable EEE using `ethtool`, but it won't stay after a reboot.

```
ethtool --set-eee enp6s0 eee off
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I did all of the things you mentioned, but it doesn't disable EEE. When I do the last step, it tells me "EEE status: enabled - active".

Comment: Hm... that's interesting. Are you sure the option is correct. Please edit your question and add output of `cat /etc/default/grub`. You can also manually disable EEE using `ethtool`.

Comment: Did you reboot after you applied the setting?

Comment: Deactivating it manually worked, though. Now it tells me "EEE status: disabled" when I type "ethtool --show-eee interface_name" into my terminal. And also, I don't quite get what you mean by "Please edit your question and add output of cat /etc/default/grub". Would you explain?

Comment: And also, I did reboot my PC after editing the kernel parameters.

Comment: Do you enter the real interface name or literally `interface_name`? Regarding posting output of `cat /etc/default/grub` I mean: run this command and post the output to your question. I asked to add output of `ip a`, but you ignored that too.

Comment: I posted the outputs. Also, I didn't literally type that.

Comment: Hello people, I've just noticed that after writing `sudo update-grub`, this appears in my terminal: `Sourcing file /etc/default/grub'` `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 2: /etc/default/grub: If: not found`

Comment: You have a typo in that file. Probably that's why the setting in grub doesn't work. The first line is wrong. You removed `#` from the beginning. Add it back and try again.

Comment: I've tried that, and it didn't work. By the way, I reinstalled Ubuntu. I tried it again after that. My ethernet card still has EEE enabled, but disabling those settings just made it disconnect less common. I can only disable EEE for sure by doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the alternate driver for your device, r8168, has eee_enable as a manipulable parameter. Let’s install it and see if it helps.

```
sudo -i
apt update
apt install -y r8168-dkms
echo “options r8168 eee_enable=0”  >  /etc/modprobe.d/r8168.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment.I've tried this now and rebooted my computer, but it doesn't seem to have deactivated EEE permanently. If I enter `ethtool --show-eee enp6s0` into my terminal, it tells me:

`EEE status: enabled - active`

Comment: But my ethernet card hasn't disconnected so far, so it might have fixed my issue in a different way. I'm not quite sure, though.

Comment: Hey, I am trying this again because I don't think it worked for me, and I've noticed something. Once I had typed `apt install -y r8168-dkms`, it told me that there is no package found that is named like that.

Comment: Did you run update first? Do you have universe repo enabled in Software and Updates? It is here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/r8168-dkms Installing it with apt will resolve all of the dependencies automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I have that enabled. When I did it again, it told me that it's already installed. It still shows me `EEE status: enabled - active`, but my ethernet hasn't disconnected so far. I'll see if it'll stay the same after rebooting.

Comment: Okay, after rebooting, my ethernet starts disconnecting again. This is strange.