# Ethernet to USB adapters Realtek disconnecting intermittently

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, ethernet, realtek

There is a question very closely related, but neither of the solutions have worked for me: [USB ethernet adapter (Realtek r8153) keeps disconnecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044127/usb-ethernet-adapter-realtek-r8153-keeps-disconnecting)

I have tried `USB_BLACKLIST="0bda:8153"` in /etc/default/tlp and adding custom rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/50-cpu-custom.rules. Ive also tried 3 different brands of adapters and they all do roughly the same thing with different rates of disconnecting. Are there any adapters that use a chip other than from Realtek I could try?

This is from dmesg:

```
[200584.034137] r8152 3-4:1.0 enx70886b811ca3: Tx status -71
[200584.034880] r8152 3-4:1.0 enx70886b811ca3: Stop submitting intr, status -71
[200584.214566] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 25
[200584.534647] usb 3-4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[200584.555161] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153, bcdDevice=30.00
[200584.555165] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[200584.555166] usb 3-4: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[200584.555168] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: CMI
[200584.555169] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 000001
[200584.690975] usb 3-4: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[200584.746198] r8152 3-4:1.0 eth0: v1.09.9
[200584.887574] r8152 3-4:1.0 enx70886b811ca3: renamed from eth0
[200584.999870] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx70886b811ca3: link is not ready
[200585.004559] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx70886b811ca3: link is not ready
[200587.647919] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx70886b811ca3: link becomes ready
[200587.648272] r8152 3-4:1.0 enx70886b811ca3: carrier on
[200685.538747] r8152 3-4:1.0 enx70886b811ca3: carrier off
[200688.192511] r8152 3-4:1.0 enx70886b811ca3: carrier on
```

Often there are other messages in /var/log/syslog, but on this occasion the first message was Tx status -71. This is using `tac` so the first messages are at the bottom:

```
Apr 23 18:49:35 pc dhclient[20695]: receive_packet failed on enx70886b811ca3: Network is down
Apr 23 18:49:35 pc kernel: [200073.926247] r8152 3-4:1.0 enx70886b811ca3: Tx status -108
Apr 23 18:49:35 pc kernel: [200073.926242] r8152 3-4:1.0 enx70886b811ca3: Tx status -108
Apr 23 18:49:35 pc kernel: [200073.926094] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 24
Apr 23 18:49:35 pc kernel: [200073.739898] r8152 3-4:1.0 enx70886b811ca3: Tx status -71
Apr 23 18:45:01 pc CRON[23435]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

Any ideas appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

your driver is r8152 (not 8153) as shown in the logs.

> [200584.746198] r8152 3-4:1.0 eth0: v1.09.9

Try blacklisting the correct device.

Comment: Hey, thanks for catching that.. as I said I have 3 dongles (4 now) I've been rotating, so that must be part of it. Actually after ordering an ASUS brand adapter that I read doesnt use the Realtek driver, I noticed some configuration for the adapter in /etc/network/interfaces that I had entered while trying different solutions. Even though pretty basic `#auto enx8cae4ce145a8 and #iface enx8cae4ce145a8 inet dhcp`, after commenting out, the log spamming stopped and my connection was more stable. Maybe these adapters are not configged the same as an eth0? Anyway, they work better without any conf.

Comment: Yes, from above you can see `usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153` right before `r8152 3-4:1.0 eth0: v1.09.9` which is a bit confusing. The Amazon brand and ASUS adapters (which have been the most reliable, even with the above config) and Pluggable, are all `ASIX AX88179 idVendor=0b95, idProduct=1790` if that helps anyone. CableMatters is the 0bda:8153 (even though it looks like the r8152 driver is controlling it). Maybe that is a problem in the other Question as well.

Comment: I appreciate the nudge to follow up on the resolution of this Question, but it appears 8153 is the correct device, even though the similarly numbered r8152 driver is using it.